# Why doesn't N[0.33333, 3] return 0.333?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, numerical-value

Basic question, other answers I found didn't really seem to address this.

`N[x,3]` seems to only work if `x` is analytic instead of numeric. But it seems it would be very simple for the function to also take a decimal and give you 3 significant digits, yet it doesn't. Can anyone give a good reason why `N` is not designed to do this? I'm aware `SetPrecision[x,3]` can do the job, but why not `N`?

```
In[277]:= N[1/3, 3]

Out[277]= 0.333

In[279]:= N[0.33333, 3]

Out[279]= 0.33333
```

Comment: Please review the marked duplicate (link inserted at the top of your question) as well as the links in the comments and answers there.  If you still have a question that you feel is *not* answered there please edit your post to clarify its difference.